How to implement .pth model on real-time?
I had trained the model from (here) and now, i want to implement it on real-time on my laptop. I tried several ways to load the model, but to no avail.
The code:
import cv2
import torch
import torchvision.transforms as transforms
from PIL import Image

# Load your ResNet model
model = torch.hub.load('pytorch/vision:v0.10.0', 'resnet50', pretrained=False)
pretrained_dict = torch.load('results/experiment/net_weights.pth', weights_only=True)
model_dict = model.state_dict()
pretrained_dict = {k: v for k, v in pretrained_dict.items() if k in model_dict}
model_dict.update(pretrained_dict)
model.load_state_dict(model_dict)
model.eval()  # Set the model to evaluation mode

# Define a transform to preprocess the input
transform = transforms.Compose([
    transforms.Resize((224, 224)),
    transforms.ToTensor(),
    transforms.Normalize(mean=[0.485, 0.456, 0.406], std=[0.229, 0.224, 0.225]),
])

# Initialize webcam
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if not ret:
        break

    # Convert the frame to a PIL image and apply transformations
    img = Image.fromarray(cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB))
    img_t = transform(img).unsqueeze(0)  # Add batch dimension

    # Perform inference
    with torch.no_grad():
        output = model(img_t)
    
    # Get the predicted class (for example, if you have a list of class names)
    _, predicted_idx = torch.max(output, 1)
    predicted_class = predicted_idx.item()  # Convert tensor to integer

    # Display the predicted class on the frame
    cv2.putText(frame, f'Predicted: {predicted_class}', (10, 30), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1, (255, 0, 0), 2)
    
    # Show the frame
    cv2.imshow('Real-time Computer Vision', frame)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):  # Press 'q' to exit
        break

# Release the capture and close windows
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

I also have a logs.json file, but I am not sure if it's useful for it.
{
    "batch_size": 32,
    "data_augmentation": "standard",
    "epochs": 50,
    "model": "resnet50",
    "optimizer": "adam",
    "pretrained": true,
    "train_biotic_stress_acc": [
        72.54237288135593,
        81.27118644067797,
        82.62711864406779,
        86.77966101694915,
        87.71186440677967,
        87.45762711864407,
        87.28813559322033,
        87.28813559322033,
        90.67796610169492,
        89.91525423728814,
        89.23728813559322,
        89.66101694915254,
        90.9322033898305,
        91.01694915254237,
        91.52542372881356,
        90.84745762711864,
        88.98305084745763,
        91.52542372881356,
        90.84745762711864,
        88.47457627118644,
        91.52542372881356,
        92.28813559322033,
        92.88135593220339,
        91.86440677966101,
        94.23728813559322,
        92.54237288135593,
        90.59322033898304,
        93.55932203389831,
        93.30508474576271,
        92.96610169491525,
        93.47457627118644,
        93.30508474576271,
        90.9322033898305,
        93.30508474576271,
        91.1864406779661,
        93.47457627118644,
        92.96610169491525,
        94.49152542372882,
        95.2542372881356,
        94.15254237288136,
        94.7457627118644,
        94.57627118644068,
        95.0,
        93.30508474576271,
        93.72881355932203,
        95.08474576271186,
        93.72881355932203,
        94.83050847457628,
        93.22033898305085,
        93.64406779661017
    ],
    "train_loss": [
        0.8282963037490845,
        0.5836613774299622,
        0.5153125524520874,
        0.43084049224853516,
        0.4390360713005066,
        0.40780237317085266,
        0.4658176600933075,
        0.42227157950401306,
        0.3433341979980469,
        0.3600851893424988,
        0.38862326741218567,
        0.36267176270484924,
        0.3588496446609497,
        0.33311688899993896,
        0.29994136095046997,
        0.32682493329048157,
        0.36273568868637085,
        0.3315748870372772,
        0.31836193799972534,
        0.33695703744888306,
        0.32421356439590454,
        0.2762307822704315,
        0.26089200377464294,
        0.2845413386821747,
        0.2687235176563263,
        0.28719162940979004,
        0.32435154914855957,
        0.27531903982162476,
        0.29826006293296814,
        0.27290764451026917,
        0.2443954199552536,
        0.2814570963382721,
        0.3201763331890106,
        0.27812349796295166,
        0.30083125829696655,
        0.23732589185237885,
        0.2818565368652344,
        0.25493666529655457,
        0.23779359459877014,
        0.280385285615921,
        0.22742299735546112,
        0.23158197104930878,
        0.23442105948925018,
        0.25980499386787415,
        0.24550049006938934,
        0.21719005703926086,
        0.23912093043327332,
        0.23146015405654907,
        0.247253879904747,
        0.22993849217891693
    ],
    "train_severity_acc": [
        66.10169491525424,
        75.50847457627118,
        77.45762711864407,
        78.47457627118644,
        77.79661016949153,
        80.50847457627118,
        78.13559322033899,
        80.2542372881356,
        81.94915254237289,
        81.69491525423729,
        79.49152542372882,
        80.59322033898304,
        79.66101694915254,
        83.22033898305085,
        85.0,
        81.35593220338983,
        81.35593220338983,
        82.71186440677967,
        84.0677966101695,
        84.7457627118644,
        83.38983050847457,
        84.91525423728814,
        86.44067796610169,
        86.86440677966101,
        85.84745762711864,
        84.49152542372882,
        84.15254237288136,
        83.98305084745763,
        82.37288135593221,
        85.59322033898304,
        89.23728813559322,
        84.15254237288136,
        84.40677966101696,
        84.49152542372882,
        85.16949152542372,
        88.30508474576271,
        84.57627118644068,
        84.57627118644068,
        85.16949152542372,
        84.83050847457628,
        87.37288135593221,
        87.45762711864407,
        87.54237288135593,
        85.08474576271186,
        86.94915254237289,
        87.45762711864407,
        87.11864406779661,
        86.35593220338983,
        87.20338983050847,
        89.15254237288136
    ],
    "val_biotic_stress_acc": [
        53.359683794466406,
        76.28458498023716,
        79.44664031620553,
        82.21343873517786,
        74.70355731225297,
        82.21343873517786,
        85.37549407114625,
        77.07509881422925,
        90.9090909090909,
        86.56126482213439,
        83.79446640316206,
        86.16600790513834,
        73.51778656126483,
        89.32806324110672,
        85.7707509881423,
        87.35177865612648,
        89.32806324110672,
        78.26086956521739,
        78.26086956521739,
        83.79446640316206,
        82.21343873517786,
        86.95652173913044,
        89.32806324110672,
        83.79446640316206,
        91.699604743083,
        89.32806324110672,
        90.51383399209486,
        86.56126482213439,
        88.14229249011858,
        90.51383399209486,
        85.7707509881423,
        84.18972332015811,
        82.21343873517786,
        89.32806324110672,
        87.74703557312253,
        90.51383399209486,
        85.7707509881423,
        86.95652173913044,
        89.32806324110672,
        89.32806324110672,
        91.699604743083,
        86.56126482213439,
        88.14229249011858,
        91.699604743083,
        89.32806324110672,
        88.14229249011858,
        86.95652173913044,
        90.9090909090909,
        92.09486166007905,
        84.9802371541502
    ],
    "val_loss": [
        12.854988098144531,
        0.7233027815818787,
        0.565257728099823,
        0.3938770592212677,
        0.5002809166908264,
        0.4399007558822632,
        0.7318148016929626,
        0.6214114427566528,
        0.31451746821403503,
        0.41589120030403137,
        0.5394357442855835,
        0.3834279775619507,
        0.6205282211303711,
        0.3562229573726654,
        0.4006038308143616,
        0.3478359878063202,
        0.3223670721054077,
        0.6522853374481201,
        0.5050507187843323,
        0.5499345064163208,
        0.4598318040370941,
        0.46111157536506653,
        0.2799707353115082,
        0.37483757734298706,
        0.30881232023239136,
        0.35001036524772644,
        0.33550742268562317,
        0.48047876358032227,
        0.4079080820083618,
        0.3100490868091583,
        0.38654884696006775,
        0.7133758068084717,
        0.4948892295360565,
        0.3370022475719452,
        0.34756383299827576,
        0.28952303528785706,
        0.41055554151535034,
        0.41655051708221436,
        0.4456130862236023,
        0.3225994408130646,
        0.3737548291683197,
        0.35072797536849976,
        0.35582756996154785,
        0.28029096126556396,
        0.3270091712474823,
        0.5963916182518005,
        0.4246876537799835,
        0.28707748651504517,
        0.31602567434310913,
        0.41391074657440186
    ],
    "val_severity_acc": [
        45.8498023715415,
        69.96047430830039,
        77.86561264822134,
        83.39920948616601,
        82.21343873517786,
        81.81818181818181,
        70.75098814229248,
        73.12252964426878,
        86.56126482213439,
        79.05138339920948,
        77.86561264822134,
        85.37549407114625,
        84.9802371541502,
        83.39920948616601,
        84.58498023715416,
        83.79446640316206,
        84.18972332015811,
        80.23715415019763,
        89.72332015810277,
        79.84189723320158,
        81.81818181818181,
        79.84189723320158,
        87.74703557312253,
        88.53754940711462,
        83.00395256916995,
        84.58498023715416,
        84.9802371541502,
        73.51778656126483,
        78.26086956521739,
        84.58498023715416,
        84.58498023715416,
        72.33201581027669,
        81.42292490118577,
        86.16600790513834,
        85.37549407114625,
        88.14229249011858,
        85.37549407114625,
        81.02766798418972,
        79.44664031620553,
        86.95652173913044,
        79.44664031620553,
        87.74703557312253,
        85.37549407114625,
        87.74703557312253,
        84.9802371541502,
        65.21739130434783,
        83.79446640316206,
        85.7707509881423,
        83.79446640316206,
        85.7707509881423
    ],
    "weight_decay": 0.0005
}

How do I implement my model on real-time such that it shows the severity and also the type of disease on the screen?

What bit of your code is actually failing? Is there an error message? Is it literally failing when you try to load the model in, as the first part of the question suggests, or is it failing at inference time?

I'm not so sure what "real-time" means in your situation. But I assume you were trying to observe the results in the while loop instantly after its execution, and to view the decreasing curve accordingly.
If that's your question, you should try logging tools such as tensorboard. Here is a quick tutorial on how to use it in pytorch. In short, you should insert writer.add_scaler("severity", value) to you code and use your terminal to launch a web app to observe your curve. Because it's a web app, you must refresh manually to view the latest data.
Tensorboard's interface should look like this:

